# Scala: Get value of child from parent?

Tags: scala

Trying to get values of all fields of child from parent class like this:

```
        for (field <- this.getClass.getDeclaredFields) {
          Logger.debug(field.getName)
          field.get(this)
        }
```

and got error

> Exception: Class models.Model$$anonfun$4 can not access a member of
>   class models.Good with modifiers "private"
>   at line

```
field.get(this)
```

In Good class I don't have private fields:

```
class Good(id: Option[String]) extends Model[realGood](id){
  lazy val title: String = this.load[String](realObject.get.title)
  lazy val cost: Double = this.load[Double](realObject.get.cost)
}
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: What line is pointed by the error message ? I think looking at a Scala class via Java reflection might be dangerous as when Scala is compiled to bytecode, the compiler performs a lot a dirty tricks to be compatible with Java bytecode. You should use Scala reflection instead

Comment: Most probably `this` is wrong. You might be within a function and `this` is an anonymous inner class of the class you would like to get the fields. BTW, in Scala every field is private, only the accessor and modifier methods visibility can be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, Scala's conversion to java bytecode isn't always straightforward (though it's usually pretty predictable, once you get the hang of it). In particular, public fields in Scala compile to a private field with a public getter in java bytecode:

```
fukaeri:~ dlwh$ cat zzz.scala
class Good(id: Option[String]) {
  lazy val title: String = ???
  lazy val cost: Double = ???
}

fukaeri:~ dlwh$ scalac zzz.scala
fukaeri:~ dlwh$ javap -private Good
Compiled from "zzz.scala"
public class Good {
  private java.lang.String title;
  private double cost;
  private volatile byte bitmap$0;
  private java.lang.String title$lzycompute();
  private double cost$lzycompute();
  public java.lang.String title();
  public double cost();
  public Good(scala.Option<java.lang.String>);
}
```

You can see that `Good` has private fields for each of your declared public fields, in addition to public getters. Because the fields are `lazy val`, they also have computation methods for initialization, and there's a `bitmap$0` field to ensure that the lazy vals are initialized only once.

In your loop, you can use `field.setAccessible(true)` to fix your exception.